# memory leak from method in analyzer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, analyzer

Im nearing the end of my first app and im trying to go through my errors and memory management and clean everything up.

In the analyzer in xcode the following line comes up as a "potential memory leak"

```
- (NSMutableArray *) convertStringToASCIIMutableArray:(NSString *)stringIn {
    NSLog(@"call:convertStringToASCIIMutableArray");

    NSMutableArray *arrayOut = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:stringIn.length];
    //NSMutableArray *arrayOut = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:stringIn.length];

    for (int i=0; i<stringIn.length; i++) {
        unichar ch = [stringIn characterAtIndex:i];
        if (ch > 96 && ch<123) ch = ch - 32; // convert to all capitals
        [arrayOut insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithChar:ch] atIndex:i];
    }
    return arrayOut;
}
```

But when i remove the alloc call (as in the commented line or with an autorelease) the app crashes. Anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: it's very important to know whether you're using ARC or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didnt really solve my problem per se, but I converted my project to compile with the new Automatic Reference Counting (ARC, thanks @Kurt Revis and @Byron for bringing this feature to my attention)

To convert my project I just went to edit>Refactor>Convert to Obj-C ARC. Then I had to conform to the new rules of memory management as prompted after doing the "check" presented in the refactoring window. Essentially I had to remove some releases in my dealloc method, but it came up with some alerts in the issue navigator to tell me what to do.

ARC seems to be great. More info available here:

[Steffen Itterheim](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/)

Answer (score 0):

"arrayOut" isn't autoreleased if you are in a manual reference counting environment.

Change `return arrayOut` to `return [arrayOut autorelease]` and the array will be released at the end of the current runloop.

Comment: this doesnt work either. It says that arrayOut has been sent autorelease too many times

Comment: the best practice for non ARC is to return an autoreleased object, not to call autorelease in the receiving method which is what I assume you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing anything here. The "potential leak" is there because you're creating the mutable array using alloc-init and not releasing it when the method completes. Since you are returning the object, I recommend you create an autorelease version.

Now for the app crashing when using an autorelease version, you'll have to look at where it is crashing and what you're doing leading up to the crash. Do you know about setting up a breakpoint when an exception is raised? If not, follow this and the code will stop at the line when the crash happens so you can debug it:

- Press Command+6 in xcode
- Click on the + button in lower left corner
- Select Add exception breakpoint
- Set options for All exceptions, on throw and hit Done.

Comment: Ive used breakpoints for trial and error debugging but this seems more powerful thanks. I'll try this